# How to fix buttons above footer using flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using Materializecss to create React app. I have already applied flex inside my app class. And now I want to apply flex inside main tag where buttons get fixed at bottom of main tag & above the footer.

I have tried {margin-top: auto;} , justify-content: flex-end which didn't help. The buttons always print after content class. I can set the height of the content class, but small devices render view badly and it's not fixing my problem.

JSX code:

```
<div className="app">
 <header> <header>
 <main>
   <div className="box">
   <div className="content"> Long text less than 100 words <div>
   <div className="buttons"> <button> Button-1 </button> <button> Button-2 </button> 
   <div>
 <main>
 <footer><footer>
<div>

My css
app {
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 flex-direction: column;
}

main {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

I want to stick my button above the footer. My content class has 100 words then the button should stick above the footer not rendered after the content class.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't applied `display:flex` etc to the main element. If you do that the `margin-top:auto` will work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: ;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <header>header </header>
  <main>
    <div class="box">box</div>
    <div class="content"> Long text less than 100 words </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button> Button-1 </button>
      <button> Button-2 </button>
    </div>

  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.